# Update specific value by name into specific index in Multidimensional

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
[{
    "index1": [
        {"name_a":"value_a","name_b":"value_b"}
    ],
    "index2": [
        {"name2":"value_a","name2":"value_b"}
    ]
}];
```

I need to change by index, value inside name ex: index1 -> name_b = value_c
Can anyone help me?

Comment: `arr[0]["index1"][0]["name_b"] = "value_c"`.

Comment: Thanks Luk.
I test now

Comment: It's work :-)  Thanks Luk